# How to take screenshot of Recyclerview when application is closed and Items updating from Backgound service class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an application, I am using `recyclerView` to show the data. I am add list items from background `service` class and showing it in `RecyclerView` in `MainActivity` class and at particular time using `service` class I am taking screenshot of that `recyclerView` and sending it to server. when the application is in foreground it is working fine by taking screenshot and sending it to server.

The problem is when I am taking screenshot at particular time using `service` class and I am out of the application it taking screenshot but `list items` data is not showing in the screenshot.

Sorry for my English...
Thanks in Advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does your background service use START_STICKY ?

Comment: No Service.START_NOT_STICKY

Comment: before taking the screen shot can you check whether the recycler view is empty. I hope it is empty.  In android if any app goes background for long time the system kills the app and re initialize it, that time your data in recycler view is lost may be

Comment: I am updating recycler view data for every one minute,if it reaches to 60min it should take automatically screenshot